# Pod Init with default option set to OSX & not IOS for CocoaPods in Swift using Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, cocoapods, podfile

I closed my **Xcode** project & went into the project directory & typed

```
pod init
```

And it made a **Podfile** like

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Test1' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Test1

end
```

Notice the 2nd line - **platform :ios, '9.0'** but mine is a Mac Desktop app

So I had to manually change it to use **platform :osx, '10.12'**

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :osx, '10.12'

target 'Test1' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Test1

end
```

Is there an option to directly create one for Mac Desktop App like **pod init --mac** or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no option --mac or anything equivalent at this moment.

You can check all the available options for pod init here: https://guides.cocoapods.org/terminal/commands.html#pod_init